# Summing up combinations of column values

Tags: r, for-loop, combinations

I have a data frame with two columns that look like

```
richness<- data.frame ("replicate_id"=c("1", "9", "10"), 
                       "richness"= c(3, 2, 4))
```

I am trying to get a result where I have all combinations of the `replicate_id` and the sum of `richness` with the associated replicates so

```
[1] - 3

[9] - 2

[10] - 4

[1+9] - 5

[1+10] - 7

[9+10] - 6

[1+9+10] - 9
```

Ultimately, I don't care about the `replicate_id` and would just like the resulting output to be something like:

```
output<- data.frame ("n.replicates"=c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3"), 
                       "richness"= c(3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9))
```

I have this in a nested for loop because I have the same data for multiple days. NOTE: this means that the length of the replicate ids change from day to day (in the example I just have three, but there are more and less depending). I have tried a million things it seems. This is what I have been using to get the combinations:

```
library(gtools)
for (i in 1:length(richness$replicate_id)){
  combs <-  data.frame(combinations (length(richness$replicate_id), i, richness$replicate_id))}
```

but everything I try after that is a bust, I tried creating a vector of the row values and then summing up if the replicate_id is in the row value vector but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, and hopefully this makes sense? I'm struggling with how to word the problem on top of just having the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and loop over each row of `richness` and then create all the combination of `richness` taking `x` at a time. We then create a dataframe of that combination and then `rbind` them together.

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(seq_along(richness$replicate_id), function(x) {
   temp = combn(richness$richness, x)
   data.frame(n.replicate = x, richness = colSums(temp))
 }))


#  n.replicate richness
#1           1        3
#2           1        2
#3           1        4
#4           2        5
#5           2        7
#6           2        6
#7           3        9
```

The intermediate step without `do.call` parameter returns

```
lapply(seq_along(richness$replicate_id), function(x) {
  temp = combn(richness$richness, x)
  data.frame(n.replicate = x, richness = colSums(temp))
 })

#   [[1]]
#  n.replicate richness
#1           1        3
#2           1        2
#3           1        4

#[[2]]
#  n.replicate richness
#1           2        5
#2           2        7
#3           2        6

#[[3]]
#  n.replicate richness
#1           3        9
```